# How to implement modaldialog with confirmation, when you click on yes, start a method in the code behind?

Tags: modal-dialog

I have created an application page. On this page I have add some asp button with an event in the code behind. In the event I start some method.

How can I make an confirmation when I click on this button. With some text like, are you sure you ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a normal JavaScript `confirm`. Add the following attribute to your ASP.net button element:

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure??')"
```